# Can we wear lord Shiva locket around our neck?

Tags: shiva

I am planning to buy a lord Shiva locket to my husband. Please let me know can we wear lord Shiva locket around our neck?

Comment: Why do you think there will be any restriction in wearing locket of Shiva? Did you hear anything like restriction in wearing? If yes then kindly share that thought also in your question.

Comment: NO. NO NO NOT AT ALL. People must not wear God on body. Many people out of devotion or fashion or any other reason, wear locket of their beloved diety. But, this is wrong. A renowned and Genuine Guru has said that wearing God on body makes the God 'Kupita'(wrathful, angry, and displeased). This gives a lot of troubles. God is to be placed in heart, and not se an ornament on body- this all the Guruji told. I am not writing Guruji 's name for identity purpose.

Comment: Also note that God is not to be used for decorating house. Many people use Radha Krishna photos in house as decorations. Many use God Idols as decorations. And limit is crossed, sometimes people even Make House lamps in Shape of Ganesha. And Ganesha has become like a god to be used as decorations- Ganesh lamps, Ganesh Watches, Ganesh pen stands, Ganesh almirah. No soon we would start eating out of Ganesha plates and bowls.

Comment: I have just told what has been told. Rest is on you to accede with it or not. I have just given the warning and cautions. And I am not mentioning the name of Guru, for identity issues. And it feels so obscene to advertise a Guru's name.

Comment: @AnuragSingh **God on body makes the God 'Kupita'** It's getting sensitive since right now I am also wearing locket of Lord Hanuman. **God is not to be used for decorating house** It's just seems like personal advice, more like personal choice of giving respect to God. There are lots of way to show love towards God. Many shows in different ways. Some ways are so different(ex. decoration) that might looks awkward to some devotees but that doesn't mean that way is wrong. It's just different way to show love. And different or strange doesn't mean wrong. Some also make tatoos of God's name in love

Comment: @Rishabh yes. The Guruji had told that do not wear God lockets exactly to a person who was wearing Hanumaan locket. The Guruji told him to remove the locket and keep it in the temple. Even I used to wear 5 lockets of one of Om, Durga, and Hanuman and two of Shiva. And as soon as I heard him, I removed the lockets and kept it in nearby temple. Rest I'm leaving up to you.

Comment: @Rishabh and as for using God as decoration , I do remember to hear it on TV, but I do not remember from whom I heard it. Also, it is self explanatory that God should not be used as a decorative. The Guru is a genuine guru, and does not speak fancy words. He has done great Sadhana and thus he tells people based on astrology, sound astrology, numerology, and other Mantras. I do not find it right to advertise his name,  so I never mention His name.

Comment: @AnuragSingh I don't think there is problem. I personally know many who wear lockets of Gods. But i think it's hard to find scriptural reference for it.

Comment: @Anurag Singh I don't think it would be a problem at all... Lingaayats wear Shiva linga on their neck...

Comment: @Tezz yes you are right. Many yogis themselves wear Shiva, Durga, Krishna, Ganesha lockets. But they are yogis. I think this "God should not be worn on body" is for normal Household people, because the very Guru who said- "Don't wear lockets" was wearing a Side [Chunari](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBdHbrWKeqThGrhS_1kOGHIqjZX8UtMn86MtF9_VGBiDvJEDniVw) with Krishna photo, as He preaches for Narayana. But he himself has warned not to wear locket as it makes God 'Kupita'. Also, he is a Yogi Guru, so we cannot say-he wears so we can also wear, as we cannot compare to him.

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes. In fact wearing God locket has become so common. I have been wearing Lockets since childhood. And as Rishabh said, it is a thing of devotion. But still there are limits. For example, a great Shiva devotee may want to offer Him ketaki flower out of devotion, but we know it is prohibited. But maybe, if devotion is extremely strong, such prohibitions may not stand, and Maheshvara may bless him also who offer Him ketaki out of devotion.

Comment: If we can wear any Ornaments or any symbols of gods like "OM" then i dont think any issue in wearing god lockets